# What are the arguments to Conrec.contour in concec.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, contour

I'm trying to build a contour plot with d3.js and conrec.js

In Jason's example code for [conrec.js](https://github.com/jasondavies/conrec.js/blob/master/README.md), I can't interpolate what each argument to the *contour()* attribute of a *Conrec* object should be.  Here is his example from the [github README](https://github.com/jasondavies/conrec.js/blob/master/README.md):

```
var data = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1], [0, 1, 0]];
var c = new Conrec;
c.contour(data, 0, 2, 0, 2, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 3, [0, 1, 2]);
// c.contours will now contain vectors in the form of doubly-linked lists.
// c.contourList() will return an array of vectors in the form of arrays.
```

It's unclear what the arguments to *c.contour* should be in the general case because the semantic meanings of zeroes and twos are overloaded here.

Can I get a general description of each argument?

Answer (score 2):

This is the doc in the source code here https://github.com/jasondavies/conrec.js/blob/master/conrec.js:

```
/**
   * contour is a contouring subroutine for rectangularily spaced data
   *
   * It emits calls to a line drawing subroutine supplied by the user which
   * draws a contour map corresponding to real*4data on a randomly spaced
   * rectangular grid. The coordinates emitted are in the same units given in
   * the x() and y() arrays.
   *
   * Any number of contour levels may be specified but they must be in order of
   * increasing value.
   *
   *
   * @param {number[][]} d - matrix of data to contour
   * @param {number} ilb,iub,jlb,jub - index bounds of data matrix
   *
   *             The following two, one dimensional arrays (x and y) contain
   *             the horizontal and vertical coordinates of each sample points.
   * @param {number[]} x  - data matrix column coordinates
   * @param {number[]} y  - data matrix row coordinates
   * @param {number} nc   - number of contour levels
   * @param {number[]} z  - contour levels in increasing order.
   */
  Conrec.prototype.contour = function(d, ilb, iub, jlb, jub, x, y, nc, z) {
```

Comment: Oop! My mistake. I should have read through the docs more carefully before posting here.